# Laravel PHP: Having trouble using nest()

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to use 'nest()' in Laravel PHP by taking 2 views, 1) The layout (layouts\master.blade.php) and 2) The form (forms\new-video.php).

However when I use the 'nest()' function, all I am seeing is the output from 'master.blade.php' and not the form from 'forms.new-video.blade.php'.

**Controller:**

```
class VideosController extends BaseController {

/**
 * The video model
 *
 * @var \Models\Video
 **/
protected $video;


//  Use this variable for the repository

protected $videoRepo;

protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

  public function create()
  {
    $data = array('type' => 'video');
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('forms.new-video', $data)
        ->nest('form', 'forms.new-video');
  }
}
```

EDIT: Here is my 'master.blade.php' layout(template):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" <?php echo asset('css/style.css')?>" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
        form ul {list-style: none}
        .navbar {border-radius: 0px;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pictures and Videos</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li {{ (Request::is('pics_vids') ? 'class="active"' : '') }}>{{ link_to_route('overview', 'Home') }}</li>
                    <li {{ (Request::is('pics_vids') ? 'class="active"' : '') }}>{{ link_to_route('overview', 'Home') }}</li>
                    <li {{ (Request::is('pics_vids/new_video') ? 'class="active"' : '') }}>{{ link_to_route('new_video', 'New Video') }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

/* Content is being called in my 'container' <div> */

    <div class="container">
        @if (Session::has('message'))
            <div class="flash alert">
                <p>{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
            </div>
        @endif

/* Call up the content here  */

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I know I'm not using the 'nest()' method properly since Laravel is still new to me.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use layouts in 2 main ways in Laravel:

**1. Controller Templates**

In your controller you have:

```
$this->layout->content = \View::make('forms.new-video', $data);
```

In your `master.blade.php` you have this where you want the content to be placed:

```
{{ $content }} // When using controller templates you don't use @yield
```

And in your `new-video` view you have whatever html you need.

**2. Template Inheritance**

You controller doesn't need to extend `BaseController` for this to work. And in your action you return the view not assign it, like so:

```
return \View::make('forms.new-video', $data);
```

In your `master.blade.php` you use `@yield` where you want to include your content:

```
@yield('content');
```

In your `new-video` view you need to specify that the view `@extents` your master layout and define a section named `content` that will be included in your layout:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    // Your form html goes here
@stop
```

---

In your case you can just use `$this->layout->content = \View::make('forms.new-video', $data);` in your controller and `{{ $content }}` instead of `@yield` in your master layout.

Comment: I tried doing that but when I click on the link for 'New Video', the webpage still just shows the layout for 'master.blade.php' and the container that is supposed to contain my form with 'new-video.blade.php', is still blank.

Comment: This should work. Please post your template files so I can have a look.

Comment: I see your problem now. You're mixing controller templates with Blade template inheritance. Does your `forms.new-video` view start with `@extend('layouts.master')` and has a `@section('content')`?

Comment: I added '@section('content') and '@stop' to my form 'new-video.blade.php' and now it appears fine.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Bogdan, if you edit your answer above to include '@section('content)', I'll give your answer the checkmark.  Thanks!